# Bot + Customer communication with human agent as moderator between the conversation

Tags: botframework, bots, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am basically trying to implement a complex product that has following features

[image]

1. Customer can send message to our support/bot via different communication channels.
2. Communicate Channels customer side: Should have integration for famous communication channels like Line, whatsApp, Telegram etc (Have a iOS/Android SDKs is plus point)
3. Customer's message (Plain Text) send over server for further processing. i.e check wether bot is turned on/off, If bot is ON message is passed to our NLP engine (dialogFlow for example) to get the intent and perform the action get the final response. but
4. Final response should not be passed directly to the customer, but it should first come to an human support agent (moderator), s/he approve and send the response to the respective customer

   4.1 Some more features
   Human agent can turn on/off the bot for any particular customer.
   Human agent can send response to customer and Train the bot for similar queries from guest in future. Human agent can change his/her can be away at any time, in this case only bot will serve the customer with auto generated response.

I have good experience in making bots via dialogFlow. but this not fulfil my above features requirements. I am searching for any similar product to clone that have the above (all/some) feature.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking to integrate Bot Framework connected to an agent hub. Bot Framework allows you to build one bot logic, serving multiple channels which you mentioned.
There is a Human Handoff scenario which allows you to connect the Bot Framework to an agent hub, where the bot in your example can serve as a proxy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-design-pattern-handoff-human?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

A few code samples can be found here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/f45a096cdc8b6938d6f1090e8bdc7475706ab81b/experimental/handoff-library/csharp_dotnetcore/samples

Alternatively, you could use the Bot Framework as an intermediator without 3rd party agent hub. A sample can be found here: https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample

Training of the bot will be done in DialogFlow in your case, or you could also use LUIS to achieve this.